# Django INSTALLED_APP Resolving to "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: django, apscheduler

The pip module Im using needs to be included in installed apps as such:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'django_apscheduler',
...
]
```

But I keep getting the following when I build my app:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_apscheduler'

Even though the app is clearly listed in my `pip list`.  The module in question is [Django APScheduler](https://github.com/jarekwg/django-apscheduler).

EDIT: Ive already installed the module via `pip install django_apscheduler`, but it is listed in `pip list` as:

`django-apscheduler # using - as opposed to _`

EDIT 2: Full trace:

```
+ python3 manage.py test --settings=grin_app.settings.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_apscheduler'
```

Answer (score 1):

this error happens when you have NOT installed the app.

run `pip install django_apscheduler` and try again.

make sure you are installing it in your python environment or in your appropriate virtual environment

Comment: I should have stated that Ive already installed the pip module.

Comment: The pip module is spelled using a dash and not an underscore, tho `django-apscheduler`

Comment: I don't know how this is working for you. I just tried again and it doesn't work unless I use `django_apscheduler` I get the same error you were getting if I use the dash `django-apscheduler`

Comment: You mean when you pip install or when you use `django-apscheduler` in INSTALLED_APPS?  When I pip install, both of the "spellings" resolve to the same package installation.

Comment: I added the full trace to the question above

Comment: I meant in INSTALLED_APPS